# How to config CI server with Hudson/SVN/Sonar/MSBuild

Tags: svn, msbuild, continuous-integration, hudson, sonarqube

I have installed a CI Server with hudson/SVN/Sonar plugin/msbuild plugin to build and analyse my C# code (ecosystem C# plugin installed).

The problem is when I create a job I get an error :

```
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01/bin/java" -cp C:\hudson\jobs\test\workspace\sonar-runner3271937888694838.jar;C:\hudson\jobs\test\workspace\sonar-batch-bootstrapper15605874800135.jar org.sonar.runner.Main -D project.settings=C:\hudson\jobs\test\workspace\trunk\test\sonar-project.properties
Project settings: C:\hudson\jobs\test\workspace\trunk\test\sonar-project.properties
Runner version: 1.1
Server: http://localhost:9000
Work directory: C:\hudson\jobs\test\workspace\.sonar
17:04:03.874 WARN  Derby database should be used for evaluation purpose only
17:04:03.877 INFO  Create JDBC datasource
17:04:04.408 INFO  Initializing Hibernate
17:04:07.179 INFO  No '.sln' file found or specified: trying to find one...
17:04:07.186 WARN  No '.sln' file specified, and none found at the root of the project: C:\hudson\jobs\test\workspace\.
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: org.picocontainer.PicoLifecycleException: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public final void org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectBuilder.start()', instance 'org.sonar.plugins.csharp.core.VisualStudioProjectBuilder@44be9164, java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:155)
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:58)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:52)
        ...
```

I think that it doesn't find the .sln file, but when I deactivate the SVN OR Sonar in the job it's OK.

I configured in my job :
- SVN (Url to the svn server is OK)
- Msbuild (path to `C:\hudson\jobs\test\workspace\trunk\test\test.sln` is OK)
- Sonar (path to `C:\hudson\jobs\test\workspace\trunk\test\sonar-project.properties` is OK)

My sonar-project.properties file (the .sln file and sonar-project.properties  are in the same directory):

```
sonar.projectKey=test_app

sonar.projectVersion=0.1

sonar.projectName=test project

sources=.

sonar.language=cs
```

My goal is that each developer's commit on the svn "run" a hudson job (with a build and a analysis of the code with msbuild and sonar).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Have you solved your problem ?

I created a batch task after the build  :

> cd C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Contacts\workspace\ProjectName\
>
> sonar-runner -Dsonar.language=cs -Dsonar.projectName=projectName
>   -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dsources="." -Dsonar.projectKey=projectKey

It's working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the additional sonar property called: sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file="name of the sln file" with path relative to the Workspace directory and you will be good to go.

More such properties can be found here: [Sonar CSharp Core Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/sonar-csharp-core-plugin)